# CORS issue during routing in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, cors

I am trying to connect my angular app to my node server and I don't want to keep my routes in server file so I have a node server file which looks like this

```
    var express         = require('express');
    var path            = require('path');
    var bodyParser      = require('body-parser');
    var morgan          = require('morgan');  
    var app             = express();
    var router          = express.Router(); 
    var port            = process.env.PORT || 3000;
    var mongoose        = require('mongoose');
    var cors            = require('cors');

    app.use(cors())
    var db ='mongodb://localhost:27017/demo'  
    mongoose.connect(db,function(err){
      if(err){
        console.log("err");
      }
      else{
        console.log("coonected to db");
      }
    })


    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(morgan('dev'));


    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname,'views'));
    app.set('view engine','ejs');
    app.engine('html',require('ejs').renderFile);

    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'app')));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));

    app.get('/',function(req,res){
        console.log("you have reached server");
        res.json('wtf');
    })


    module.exports = app;
    require('./route.js');
    app.listen(port);
```

In route.js I have my route like this

```
    var login   = require ('./api/login');
    var app     = require('./server')
    app.get('/login',login.authenticate);
```

It works fine if I use it on node server but if I use it on angular server it shows this error:

Redirect from 'localhost:3000/login' to 'localhost:3000/login/' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.

It only happens to the routes that I define in `route.js`. If I define the same route in `server.js` they work fine.

PS: I have also used

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 'Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,content-type,application/json');
    next();
});
```

and some variation of this code but nothing works if I want to route to login url which is in my route file

Comment: Why are you making your app configuration inside routes.js?

Comment: I am new to node and I want to keep the route in a separate module

Comment: That is fine but this is a configuration on your express settings, it is fine to keep your express related configs in your server.js. However, if you can add the usage inside routes.js maybe we can find a solution.

Comment: Nevermind I didn't see your routes.js already added. Now tell me this do you think app in routes.js refer to the same thing in server.js?

Comment: yes I think they both are same

Comment: No they are not.. one is `var app = express()` one is `require('./server')` your server.js contains a lot of things. What makes you think it will refer to the `var app` variable?

Comment: I used console.log to see both the app variable and they seem to be same

Comment: Look.. use your logic; the one in server.js is a variable, you define it like `var app = express()`. The other is a module that includes this variable, `require('/server')`. How can they be the same? With this logic; Do you think `var path = require('path')` is the same with `require('/server')`? I edited my answer btw.

Comment: I used your answer in my code but it didn't work there is the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app inside routes.js and server.js do not refer to the same thing. Hence your "app" won't work in routes.js. If you want to use app = express() in routes.js you can add something like this inside server.js

```
var Routes = require('./routes.js');
var r = new Routes(app);
```

so in order to instantiate routes like this your routes.js should look like:

```
module.exports = function(app){
    var login   = require ('./api/login');
    app.get('/login',login.authenticate);
    ...
}
```

Old answer:

As [@Anurag Singh Bisht](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3436826/anurag-singh-bisht) also answered you should allow Cross Domain requests. My answer would be slightly different:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 'Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,content-type,application/json');
    next();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but sorry this solution does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `allow cross origin` in your server, so that your front end can access it.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
  next();
});
```

Comment: I have used this but its shows the same error but thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You need to add below code for handling the `preflight` request sending from browser.

```
const cors = require('cors')
const corsOptions = {
  origin: '*'
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions))

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 'Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,content-type,application/json');
    next();
});
```